# Oracle table having 1-M relationship with itself

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, foreign-keys, ddl

Let's say I have a table of `Staff`

```
create table staff (
    staffID number,
    staffName varchar2(255)
);
```

but each staff member has zero or more subordinates, who are also staff members.

How do I design the table?

I am thinking about adding an extra column that reference another row on the `staff` table

```
alter table staff add (subordinateID number not null);
```

in order to make it a foreign key I also have to make `subordinateID` a primary key

```
alter table staff add constraint pk primary key (staffID, subordinateID);
```

and when I am actually referencing, i.e. linking the subordinateID to the subordinate's `staffID`

```
alter table staff add constraint fk foreign key (subordinateID) references staff (staffID);
```

there is an error

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

That confuses me because I have already made `staffID` a part of the primary key? What should I do to solve this problem and how should I design the table?

Answer (score 2):

Since a staff member can have multiple subordinates, keeping a subordinate_id column is probably a bad idea - it violates 1NF. Instead, I suggest looking at it from the other direction, and per staff member keep his manager's id, which is unique:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
    staffID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    staffName VARCHAR2(255),
    managerId NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE staff ADD CONSTRAINT staff_pk PRIMARY KEY (staffID);

ALTER TABLE staff ADD CONSTRAINT staff_fk
FOREIGN KEY (managerID) REFERENCES staff (staffID);
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work as there will be multiple subordinates, what you want is a junction table that has the subordinateId and the managerid and then you can build the hierarchy from that is you want to see the whole chain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table staff (
    staffID number primary key,
    staffName varchar2(255),
    bossID number
);

alter table staff add constraint fk_staff_boss
    foreign key (bossID) references staff(staffID);
```

Comment: While this would work in most cases, I have frequently run onto organizations where one person may directly report to two people which is why I recommend a junction table.

Comment: this answer solves my problem but @HLGEM i think your idea of creating a junction table makes more sense, relational wise